# How to pass an iterated ArrayList to another activity as a JSON Array, and make it show?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Hey Stackoverflow community, when I pass the JSON Array to another Activity, it just gives "null" back, could you give me a solution ?

**EDIT** it stops, after the `onClick`

**First Activity:**

```
eingabe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dish_name);

    send.setOnClickListener(this);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);

    speicher = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("jsondata", 0);
   zugreifen können (hier private --> 0)
    editor = speicher.edit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == save) {
        FavDishes.add(eingabe);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        }
            JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(FavDishes);

        editor.putString("jsondata", jsArray.toString());
        editor.commit();
```

**second Activity:**

```
anzeige = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.anzeige);

SaveDish(anzeige.getText().toString());
speicher = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("jsondata",0);
editor = speicher.edit();



private void SaveDish(String jsondata){

    String strJson = speicher.getString("jsondata","0");//second parameter is necessary ie.,Value to return if this preference does not exist.

    if(strJson != null) try {
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(strJson);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    editor.putString("jsondata",strJson);
    editor.commit();
    //"Data 1" als key für "Schublade Data1", value Inhalt (übergebener String)
   anzeige.setText(speicher.getString("jsondata", null));
}
anzeige = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.anzeige);
```

Help would be appreciated, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over you array and for each element into you array you can parse it to JSON object then push to your json array.

Regards,

Comment: Could you please give me a short example, i wasn't able to implement it right. Sorry for the circumstances.